# Numeric value of Months in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to display my Date field from my MySQL database.

format is 2012-01-01 to 2012-01-31

Is there a way to display the month of January to 0 instead of 1?

I used strtotime to change its format

```
date('Y, n, j',strtotime($s['date']))
```

but this showed

```
2012, 1, 1
```

I want to display this as

```
2012, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do something like:

```
$time = strtotime($s['date']);
$str = date('Y, ', $time);
$str .= intval(date('n', $time)) - 1;
$str .= date(', j', $time);
```

Not sure this is the best/only way, but it should work.

EDIT: davidethell's point taken, code changed accordingly. +1 for the comment.

Comment: You'll get better performance if you just do the strtotime once into a variable such as $timeString and then use that variable in each of your successive lines. Other than that, +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer you can do it in SQL:

```
SELECT MONTH(my_date_col) - 1 AS custom_month_col;
```

Otherwise I agree with @Ynhockey

Edited (see comment):

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR('2012-03-08'),'-', (MONTH('2012-03-08') - 1), '-', DAY('2012-03-08')) AS custom_month_col;
```

Comment: This one only shows the month to zero..can you show how it will display as 2012-0-1?

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `getdate()` instead of `date()` to return the date as an array, and then concatenate the required values eg.

```
<?php
  $date = getDate(strtotime($s['date']));
  echo $date['year'].', '.($date['mon']-1).', '.$date['mday'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you only need the month output, this worked for me:

```
$month = intval(date('n',strtotime($result["Date"]))) - 1;
```

**$result["Date"]** is how the value passed from MySQL is called.